# Proving that the set of real numbers is a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I recently finished an activity provided by a professor where one of the questions was to prove that the set of real numbers is a topological space.  The hint provided was to "consider the union of open intervals" in the set of real numbers.  I am fairly certain that what I did was accurate, but I want to confirm with someone who knows the proof, or is aware of how to do the proof.  Thanks in advance.

I showed that for a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ that any union of the elements of $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to \mathcal{T}, any finite intersections (being infinitely many) of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$, and that the null set and the set $X$ belong to $\mathcal{T}$ as well, but I just didn't feel all that confident that doing that was the complete proof.

Comment: But you didn't tell us what you did.

Comment: A proof is given under "examples" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space).

Comment: @ Dylan: What means for you 'the real plane'? real line OK, complexe plane OK, but 'real plane' i don't understund what it is.

Comment: @Mohamed It's simply $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @ Najib: Dylan spoke about open intervals of the real plane...but  he just corrected his message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try something a little more general. In any (pseudo)metric space $(X,d)$, the collection of all the open balls is a base for a topology on $X$.

Let $x,y\in X$, $r,s>0$ and $z\in U= B(x,r)\cap B(y,s)$. Let $t=\min\{r-d(x,z),s-d(y,z)\}$ and $k\in B(z,t)$, so $$d(x,k)\le d(x,z)+d(z,k)<d(x,z)+t<r$$ Similarly $d(y,k)<s$.  Thus $B(z,t)\subset U$. So $U$ is union of open balls which includes.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ the collection of all unions of  open balls. It's clear that $\varnothing,X\in\mathcal{T}$ and is closed under arbitrary unions. To show that it is also closed under finite intersections. Let $U,V\in\mathcal{T}$, i.e., $U=\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ and $V=\bigcup\mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V}$ are collection of open balls. Thus

$$U\cap V=\bigcup\{A\cap B:A\in \mathcal{U},B\in \mathcal{V}\}$$

Since each $A\cap B$ is union of open balls, as we have shown, so is $U\cap V$. Hence $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology and the collection of all open balls is a base for the topology.

In particular, $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual distance is  a metric space.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $$ \cal I=\{]a,b[/(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 ; a \leq b\}$$ and $$\mathcal O=\{\mathop \cup_{u  \in \cal J} u\}$$ where $\cal J$ is a subset of $\cal I$

You have to proof:

(1) $\emptyset \in \mathcal O$ and $\Bbb R  \in \mathcal O$

(2) if $(o_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of elements of $\mathcal O$ then $o=\mathop \cup_{i \in I} o_i \in \cal O$

(3) if $v \in \cal O$ and $w \in \cal O$ then $o=v \cap w \in \cal O$